# working .htaccess configs don't work on httpd.conf

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, xampp, httpd.conf

An early heads up - I'm a beginner student with Back-end programming and for now, even .htaccess URL rewrites was a huge pain to implement.

I have XAMPP Apache installed on my Mac (not XAMPP-VM) with a website folder called "Project" inside "/htdocs". So basically a website that I'm practicing with URL looks like this - "localhost/Project"

There was one .htaccess file in my "root" ("root" is the "/Project" folder) folder and another one inside a "PHP" folder (i.e. root/PHP/.htaccess).
Root's .htaccess had the following configs:

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 403 /Project/index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)Pages 
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Pages/$1.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Whilst root/PHP's .htaccess had this:

```
Deny from all
```

Everything worked and after reading a bit more about .htaccess best practices I wanted to move all of the above configs to httpd.conf, specifically the one located inside "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf". I moved the code to that httpd (properly?), commented out everything inside the previously mentioned .htaccess files, and here's how the httpd now looks like inside:

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/Project">
    Options -Indexes

    ErrorDocument 403 /Project/index.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)Pages 
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /Pages/$1.php [L,NC]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
    
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/Project/PHP">
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

And it doesn't work. I've tried to google a solution for a while and so far completely nothing. Just in case, I'll also mention that the goal for this "CMS" project is to "write once, install anywhere".

**[EDIT]**
With some clarifications from @MrWhite, this is what the configs look like in `xamppfiles`. Also, also, `Options -Indexes` and `/Project/PHP > Require all denied` don't work as I can browse folders and access "PHP" folder from Browser. And it did not work prior to this ***EDIT*** as well.

-xamppfiles/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Include "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"
```

-xamppfiles/apache2/conf/project.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/Project">
    
    Options -Indexes
        
    ErrorDocument 403 /Project/index.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)Pages 
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Pages/$1.php [L,NC]
    </IfModule>
    
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/Project/PHP">
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: "There was one .htaccess file in my "root" folder" - What you are calling the "root" folder is really the `/Projects` directory? So, `Pages` is a subdirectory of `/Projects`?

Comment: @MrWhite apologies for misleading. Yes, that's correct, ```root``` in my context is ```/Project``` and ```Pages``` is the subdirectory of ```/Project```. Thought that calling it root further on would be proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue, which was my blind mistake.

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/Project">
    Options -Indexes
    //...
```

I was pointing to the wrong `htdocs` folder that contains my Project and the correct way was:

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Project">
```

Hope this saves some time for anyone else that would come across this.

Answer (score 0):

> *Original:*
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Pages/$1.php [L,NC]
> ```
>
> *New:*
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /Pages/$1.php [L,NC]
> ```

You shouldn't have changed anything here. You are moving the directives from `.htaccess` to a `<Directory>` section (in the server config). These are both *directory* contexts and work the same way. (You are incorrectly thinking this is a *server* or *virtualhost* context, although the target URL-path would still be wrong.)

By introducing a slash at the start of the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) the rule will never match. If it did... the additional slash you've introduced at the start of the *substitution* string (second argument) would incorrectly rewrite the request to `/Pages` in the document root, not `/Project/Pages` as would seem to be the intention.

Note that if you are moving the `.htaccess` config to `<Directory>` containers in the server config then you should *probably* disable `.htaccess` overrides altogether, since a `.htaccess` file that contains mod_rewrite directives will completely override the `<Directory>` container in the server config. For example:

```
AllowOverride None
```

Note also that `Order`, `Allow` and `Deny` are Apache 2.2 directives and formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4. On 2.4 you should be using the equivalent `Require` directive instead. For example:

```
Require all granted

Require all denied
```

---

*Extra:*

Look into creating additional `<VirtualHost>` containers for each project, store these in separate files and `include` them in the main server config, rather than modifying the main server config directly. This will allow you to host multiple (separate) websites on the same webserver.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did not use the '/' character at first in the Override rules, however I might have misunderstood what I've read in my "research". I've removed all of the ```.htaccess``` files from the ```/Project``` (root) of my website (though I'm still aiming to implement an option for it to be available later, so that it would be possible to create redirects and such from the Admin Dashboard of this CMS) and followed your other recommendations, such as ```Require``` and ```<VirtualHost>``` though nothing helped as it still doesn't work. I'll update my post